# How to make an SQL query based on some rules

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this HTML form where I have multiple input elements: text, radio, and so on. These are intended to be options, conditional items to apply in an SQL query in order to pull more specific data from a database.

For example, the first input field is a textbox, the second a radio button, and the third a SELECT with two options. With the first, I would add a *LIKE %name%* sentence in the SQL query. The second is a radio button group with, let's say, a color, so I would add a *WHERE color = $item* comparing the one chosen with the database column. The third would pretty much be just like the second.

Now, I guess I could just use *if* sentences comparing the three items, in order to know which one to add to the SQL query, but my question is: is there a **smarter** way to do it? Like an array checking if those variables are set (I'm still using an *if* here, so nevermind).

I program simple things from time to time, since I've never done anything significantly complex, but sometimes, even for simple things, no matter how hard I strive to design something, I just can't.

In this case, I really can't figure (imagine, visualize) how would I structure the PHP code along with the SQL query, in order to add the these three conditions to the *WHERE* clause.

I'd greatly appreciate if you can help me out here. If you need more details, just let me know.

Comment: Isn't null checking and generating a where condition based on that a simple way to arrange this?

Comment: @hgulyan Well, that's certainly what I have in mind, something like isset() or empty(), but I'm curious as to what approach would you use, with a code example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just build your sql statement as you go.

A simple example:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE 1=1";      // 1=1 is just an example to get the WHERE out of the way

if (first condition / certain $_POST variable is set)
{
    $sql .= " AND LIKE %...%";
}
if (second condition)
{
    $sql .= " AND something=...";
}
// etc.

// run query
```

Comment: Your code is what I have in mind, but I was thinking in another way to do it. I guess I'm striving to hard to find another way to do it, and in the way, actually contradicting the phrase: "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler."

Comment: Well, you can put the conditions in the form in different arrays (a *like* array, an "=" array, etc.) and then loop through these arrays adding the similar conditions, but I don´t think you can get it simpler than that.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Like I said, perhaps I was looking what was right there under my very nose. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just for adding another solution, I can suggest you using stored procedure.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm

You'll just need to pass values to a sp and generate where condition inside it.

There's another option to generate parameterized query in PHP to prevent SQL Injections.

Here are some links on this topic.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.php

http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_MySQL_by_examples-193.html

http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3110596.htm

http://am.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: I like the roScripts example. Thanks!